# VBA Shape.Placement property still allows resizing

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to copy the first Row from the sheet "Template and paste to the first row of all other sheets. The first row contains shapes that need to remain the same size.

When the macro is run the shapes from the "Template" are resized on all other sheets. I therefore set the placement property with this line `Shp.Placement = xlFreeFloating`.

However they continue to be resized during the paste procedure. After they have been pasted however, if the cell size is changed they are no longer resized.

How can i prevent the shapes resizing when first pasted?

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim HeaderRow As Range
    Dim Shp As Shape

    Set HeaderRow = Worksheets("Template").Range("1:1")
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        For Each Shp In ws.Shapes
            Shp.Placement = xlFreeFloating 
        Next Shp

        If ws.Name <> "Template" Then
            For Each Shp In ws.Shapes
                If Shp.TopLeftCell.Row = 1 Then
                    Shp.Delete 'Delete shapes before pasting or they multiply
                End If
            Next Shp
            
            HeaderRow.Copy
            
            ws.Range(HeaderRow.Address).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            ws.Paste

        End If
    Next ws
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub copyShapesMove()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, wsT As Worksheet, HeaderRow As Range, Shp As Shape

    Set wsT = Worksheets("Template")
    Set HeaderRow = wsT.Range("1:1")
    'set the header shapes placement property BEFORE COPYING:
    For Each Shp In wsT.Shapes
        If Not Intersect(Shp.TopLeftCell, HeaderRow) Is Nothing Then
            Shp.placement = xlMove
        End If
    Next
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If ws.Name <> "Template" Then
            For Each Shp In ws.Shapes
                If Shp.TopLeftCell.row = 1 Then
                    Shp.Delete 'Delete shapes before pasting or they multiply
                End If
            Next Shp
            
            HeaderRow.Copy
            
            ws.Range(HeaderRow.Address).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            ws.Paste
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

The above code works only in versions newer then Excel 2007, which looks to have a bug and does not care (in VBA) about 'Move but don't size with cells' property. So, the following code places the shapes to be copied dimensions in an array and adapts the size of the copied shapes after copying:

```
Sub copyShapesSameDimensions()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, wsT As Worksheet, HeaderRow As Range, Shp As Shape
  Dim arrSh, k As Long, El, arrProp

    Set wsT = Worksheets("Template")
    Set HeaderRow = wsT.Range("1:1")
    'Put the shapes to be copied dimensions in an array:
    ReDim arrSh(wsT.Shapes.Count - 1)
    For Each Shp In wsT.Shapes
        If Shp.TopLeftCell.Row = 1 Then
            arrSh(k) = Shp.Name & "|" & Shp.Width & "|" & Shp.Height & "|" & Shp.Left: k = k + 1
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve arrSh(k - 1)

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Template" Then
            For Each Shp In ws.Shapes
                If Shp.TopLeftCell.Row = 1 Then
                   Shp.Delete
                End If
            Next Shp
            
            HeaderRow.Copy
            
            ws.Range(HeaderRow.Address).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            ws.Paste

            'put the dimensions back on each shape:
            For Each El In arrSh
                arrProp = Split(El, "|")
                For Each Shp In ws.Shapes
                    If Shp.TopLeftCell.Row = 1 Then
                        If Shp.Name = arrProp(0) Then
                            Shp.Width = CDbl(arrProp(1))
                            Shp.Height = CDbl(arrProp(2))
                            Shp.Left = CDbl(arrProp(3))
                            Exit For
                        End If
                End If
                Next
            Next El
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I had just edited the question as you posted, to show that I had tried the placement property before copying. Both with``` xlMove``` and ```xlFreeFloating```. I have also changed my code to match yours exactly but still pasted shapes are resized.

Comment: @aye cee I am not sure you understood my suggestion. Your code tries setting the property in discussion **on the active sheet**. This should be done before copying, only once, on the `wsT` worksheet, `HeaderRow`... Can you share the workbook in discussion? But before I would like you to confirm that the next understanding is correct: You try copying a range, some shapes included, and on the sheet they are pasted, their dimensions are not exactly as the copied shapes. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I can share a workbook. Where do I do that?

Comment: Try sending on my personal mail (in my profile) or using a transfer site. [This one](https://easyupload.io/) is free and easy to be used.

Comment: It works exactly as it should. I mean, the shapes on the sheet where they've been copied have exactly the same dimensions as the copied ones (from "Template" sheet). What do you want, in fact?

Comment: This could be down to a difference in versions. I am working on 2007.

Comment: On all sheets the shapes differ in length based on column width.

Comment: Let me move it and try on a computer having 2007 installed

Comment: Yes, it behaves strange in 2007. Let me see how/if it can be "convinced" to do what is necessary...

Comment: @aye cee Please, test the code I added after **Edited**:. It looks that Excel 2007 has a bug and does not care about 'Move but don't size with cells' property. So, the adapted code initially places the shapes to be copied sizes in an array and correct the shapes after copying. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: It opens the code to this line ```    Debug.Print Join(arrSh, ":"): Stop```

Comment: Please, comment this line. I wanted to check the created array... Now, press F5 for the code to continue. I will adapt the code... Adapted. You can download the working workbook from [here](https://easyupload.io/6v5hei).

Comment: Yes this works well, sizes do not change.

Comment: @aye cee In fact, sizes are changed during the copying processed, but reset them in the last part of the loop. Now, the button is positioned according to the column where it used to be. If you want it to be placed at the same distance from the screen left side, it can be done, adding a new parameter to the used array...

Comment: I noticed the size change in the code and in the screen updating. What would be the parameter to add?

Comment: @aye cee `Shp.Left`. Should I adapt the code for this property, too?

Comment: @aye cee Should I understand that the above code didn't answer your question? If not, what else do you expect from it, please?

Comment: if you could adapt for Shp.Left that would be fantastic. I was just reading up on it trying to understand.

Comment: @aye cee OK. I asked about it almost an hour before... I will adapt the code in less than a minute. Adapted it.

Comment: Sorry have been away from the computer. I only just noticed that you offered to include it, which is why I just mentioned it. Sometimes its hard to be clear in a message. Thank you!

Comment: @aye cee No problem. Did you test the updated code?

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks again for your help!